# Is there a way (like planning algorithms) to draw a successive polyline to fill a specific shape (like triangle)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, algorithms, opencv

there is a specific shape (like triangle) area, i am trying to develop an program to draw a successive polyline inside the triangle to fill the triangle, one line 3 layers

[image: ing]

this post demonstrates some algorithms to solve this category of problems.

none of them is suitable for this task, any ideas?

Comment: Why is this post tagged [machine-learning] and [deep-learning]?  The problem can be solved using just [algorithms].

Comment: CNC milling machines are programmed to execute solutions to this exact problem, but I do not know whether the machinist has to manually enter code to do the "hogging out", or if any of the programming languages have "meta" instructions to generate the needed low-level instructions.

Comment: 3-D printing software does have instructions to compile a 3-D shape file down to a series of low-level instructions to fill this kind of shape.  Typically, the instructions generate parallel raster scan-lines, rather than modified triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would not it be easier to simply apply geometric computation to your triangle to get smaller triangles whose vertices can be used for the polyline.?

With [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/)

You have a triangle.

```
shp = Triangle[];
Graphics[{LightGray, shp}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

A [`ScalingTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingTransform.html) about the [`RegionCentroid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionCentroid.html) can be performed with [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html) to get smaller inner triangles. Below, `shp` is scaled by factors 0.8, 0.6, and 0.4 for the inner triangles.

```
scaledShps =
  TransformedRegion[shp,
     ScalingTransform[{#, #},
      RegionCentroid@shp]] & /@ Range[.8, .4, -.2];
SeedRandom[456]
Graphics[{LightGray, shp, Riffle[Hue /@ RandomReal[1, Length@scaledShps], scaledShps]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Each of `scaledShps` has the vertices as the first argument. [`Map (/@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) to collect these and [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) them into a single [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html).

```
Graphics[{
  LightGray, shp,
  Orange, Thick, Line@Flatten[First /@ scaledShps, 1]
  }]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Get more layers by increasing the number of scaling factors. For example, from .95 to .05 in steps of -.05

```
scaledShps =
  TransformedRegion[shp,
     ScalingTransform[{#, #},
      RegionCentroid@shp]] & /@ Range[.95, .05, -.05];
Graphics[{
  LightGray, shp,
  Orange, Thick, Line@Flatten[First /@ scaledShps, 1]
  }]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Wolfram recently released a [free Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/) that can be called from many languages (Python, C, ...) so you can use the above code directly in your project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This algorithm is best-suited to convex shapes, such as triangles.  If the shape is concave or contains holes, the shrunken shapes may cover areas that were not in the original shape.